# ProGuard with JavaFX and JDOM2

Tags: java, proguard

Im using the ProGuard GUI to obfuscate my jar but Im having some troubles. Special about my jar is that I use the libraries javafx and jdom2.

What I did so far:

- Added the input jar
- Added the output jar
- Added the libraries rt.jar, jdom-2.0.6.jar, jfxrt.jar

I dont know exactly how to fill this form to make it work properly. I tried several thing but I keep getting different errors.

[image: UI Obfuscation]

Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: "Do you have any experience with it?" is not a real question and "I keep getting different errors" is not a real problem description. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: is your code working without proguard ?

Comment: which of the building frameworks are you using for building your project? Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 3):

if your code is working without proguard, you will have to exclude the external dependencies in you proguard offuscation list like so.

In normal cases proguard will try to offuscate all.
Try to add to your proguard config file :

```
-dontoptimize

-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/jce.jar

# Save meta-data for stack traces
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Rename FXML files together with related views
-adaptresourcefilenames **.fxml,**.png,**.css
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml
-adaptclassstrings

# Keep all annotations and meta-data
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

# Keep entry-point class
-keep class com.zenjava.test.javafx_and_proguard.MainApp {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Keep all classes inside application
-keep,allowobfuscation class com.zenjava.test.javafx_and_proguard.** {
}

# Keep names of fields marked with @FXML attribute
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}
```

source of code : https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/master/examples/javafx-proguard-gradle/proguard.conf

Comment: as a geek, will recommand you to edit your proguard config file in order to edit it. This editor is not very copy/paste friendly ....

Comment: I mean the editor used on top is not facilitating editing of your file. Do it manualy better and safer.

Comment: @jeorfvre Thx for helping me out. Actually I dont know how to do it manually so I want to use the GUI. in the solution you wrote I cannot find hints to JDOM2.